# Screencast wont record Spen actions on my Application

Tags: android, jailbreak, samsung-mobile

I just rooted my Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 to record writing on my Application. My app inherits and builds on the Spen Classes provided by Samsung.

I want to be able to record the notations I make on screen with my hand/stylus. Screen cast however is not capturing this. It captures the motions but it doesn't capture the color/drawing associated with the motion.

I tried using screencast with sPen itself and that works perfectly well. There is something about the editor in my app that Screencast doesn't recognize.

This seems to be an unique problem. I have searched quite a bit for this, with no avail.

I don't even know where to start while identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with ScreenCast not my Application. I used "SCR Free" Recorder instead.